# Why don't gcc/clang vectorize 128-bit SIMD intrinsics into 256-bit when possible?

Tags: gcc, x86, clang, intrinsics, avx2

Suppose I have this function:

```
void test32(int* a, int* b, size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        a[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}
```

Clang and gcc both produce 256-bit SIMD when compiled with `-O3 -march=core-avx2` ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3sYcan53G)).

Now suppose I have this function:

```
void test128(__m128i* a, __m128i* b, size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        a[i] = _mm_add_epi32(a[i], b[i]);
    }
}
```

With the same CFLAGS, clang and gcc both refuse to vectorize this to 256-bit ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Mcb8bhbfM)).

**The naive code (auto-vectorized) therefore processes twice as many elements per iteration compared to the manually vectorized SSE2 code**. How does this make sense? Is there a way to instruct the compiler to vectorize 128-bit SIMD intrinsics into 256-bit when AVX2 is available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately no, I don't know of a compiler option to re-vectorize intrinsics (or GNU C native vectors) to a wider type.  **That's one reason not to manually vectorize in the first place for cases that easily auto-vectorize.**

It's sometimes useful to be able to tell the compiler what vectorization strategy you want it to use, and that's what intrinsics are for.

If compilers rewrote them too aggressively, that would be bad in some cases.  Like cleanup loops following a loop with wider vectors, you might use 128-bit to leave fewer scalar elements after.  Or maybe you have 16-byte alignment but not 32, and you care about Sandybridge specifically (where misaligned 32-byte load/store are quite bad).  Or you're on Haswell server where 256-bit AVX can reduce max turbo (at least for FP math instructions), so you only want to use 256-bit vectors in some functions that will be running in some phases of your program.

Basically it's a tradeoff between how close to writing in asm it is, for clever humans to specify what they want, vs. just giving a way to tell the compiler about the program logic in a way it can understand and optimize (like the `+` operator: that doesn't mean you'll get an asm `add` instruction).

MSVC and ICC tend to take intrinsics even more literally than GCC/clang, not doing constant propagation through them.  GCC/clang's choice of how to treat intrinsics is sensible in a lot of ways.

If you have a trivially vectorizable problem like this (no loop carried dependencies or shuffles), and you want your code to be compilable for future wider vector instructions, **use OpenMP `#pragma omp simd` to tell the compiler you definitely want it vectorized.**  This kind of problem is what OpenMP is for, if you don't enable full optimization to get compilers to try to auto-vectorize every loop.  (At gcc `-O3`, or clang `-O2`.  Also -O2 for GCC12.)  OpenMP can get the compiler to vectorize FP math in ways that it normally wouldn't be allowed to without `-ffast-math`, e.g. FP reductions like sum of an array.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, Peter. Some context: I want to apply PACKSSWB to a large array of words and produce a large array of bytes.

When I write a loop with `_mm_packs_epi16` and compile with `-march=core-avx2`, the instruction changes to VPACKSSWB, but the vector width remains 128 bits (`xmm` registers): https://godbolt.org/z/zb64sfYz5

It would be great if the compiler could expand `_mm_packs_epi16` to `_mm256_packs_epi16` when AVX2 is available. I agree that for trivial cases it's best to leave it to the auto-vectorizer :)

Sorry for over-simplifying the original question!

Comment: @ElliotGorokhovsky: `vpacksswb ymm` is two separate in-lane packs, unfortunately, so you need a `vpermq` as well.  Yeah, it would be nice if the compiler could do that for us, or if there was some good way to express a scalar saturating i16 -> i8 conversion which the compiler could then auto-vectorize.  (I haven't tried to look for an idiom that compilers could recognize for that.)  BTW, narrowing conversion is a pretty light-weight operation; if you have a large array, best to do this on the fly while it's being generated or being read, so data doesn't need another round trip into L1d.

Comment: Thanks for the advice -- luckily we have a bit of additional work in between the load and store (not just a single `vpacksswb`), so hopefully it's not too inefficient!

Luckily for our application order isn't important. Appreciate the pointer that it's in-lane though.

Comment: @ElliotGorokhovsky: Just for fun, I had a go: https://godbolt.org/z/xnT66sYjo .  GCC uses `pmaxsw` / `pminsw` + `pand` to clamp, then (/facepalm) uses `vpackuswb` + `vpermq` to actually pack.  Clang widens to dword elements even with `(signed char)-128` and stuff in the ternary.  So both are pretty much a disaster compared to manual vectorization.

Comment: @ElliotGorokhovsky: Oh, if order isn't important, then yeah you need to manually vectorize for AVX2 specifically if you want maximum efficiency.  There's no way for the compiler to know (or for you to tell it) that order doesn't matter, so anything you write would have to explicitly introduce a shuffle instead of mapping `s[i]` to `c[i]` if you wanted it to vectorize without the compiler having to introduce a `vpermq`.  This is a good example of a non-trivial vectorization case where you *are* gaining something from manually vectorizing for a wider vector width.

Comment: And yeah if you do have some other work as part of the same pass that narrows, that's good.  You might still consider cache-blocking for L2 size to reduce off-core memory bandwidth requirements, if that can be done conveniently with any earlier or later stage.

Comment: Rather than `vpermq` to fix ordering, why not just blend the inputs? The blends can run on ports 0 and 1 so that you aren't adding more port 5 pressure.

Comment: Hmm, 2x `vpblendd` for each `vpacksswb`?  Interesting.  Yeah that could work even though it's more front-end uops.  Depends on surrounding code, whether you're up against a front-end or port 5 bottleneck.  Fortunately you don't need a finer-grained blend, since `vpblendw` is 1 uop for port 5 on Skylake, or for p15 on Alder Lake.  And `vpblendvb` is 2 uops on Intel, or 3 on Alder Lake.  Note that more uops also means more space in the ROB, potentially important for out-of-order exec's ability to see farther, e.g. to do future loads across page boundaries which HW prefetch doesn't handle.